# Add to the first row only in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm doing Find in Files in Notepad++ and I need to add some commas to the end of the first row of each csv in a folder.

Adding to every row with regular expression $ will not help.

Column 1 row 1 will always start with "Ab" and that string will be nowhere else in the whole csv, but what comes after Ab varies.

With regular expressions I tried: find "Ab....." and replace it with "Ab.....,," but column 2 row 1 does not have the same amount of characters in each csv so that didn't work.

So for example, I want to add 2 commas after d but not after 2 or 4 for thousands of csvs where "d" and "g" vary.

```
Abg, d
y, e,1,2
c, f,3,4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using N++'s regular expression, you could do the following:

find: `^(Ab.*)$`

replace: `\1,,`

This matches `Ab` only if it's at the beginning of the line (the `^` is the 'begging' switch) followed by anything (`.*` says to repeat an 'any character match') up to the end of the line (the `$` is the 'eol' switch). The `()` allows us to save the regex results so we can then use them later.

On the replace line, the `\1` says to use the first parenthesized match as our replacement (the `(Ab.*)` portion) followed by 2 commas.

**NOTE:** ensure you don't have the `. matches newline` checkbox checked when doing the regex search as the `.*` would then evaluate to mean 'the rest of the document'.

So given your example above:

```
Abg, d
y, e,1,2
c, f,3,4
```

Would then be

```
Abg, d,,
y, e,1,2
c, f,3,4
```

You could then do 'Replace all in all open documents' to apply this regex to all files you have opened.

Hope that can help.